# how to keep the filled data remain after a incomplete form submit?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

```
<html>
    <head><script type="text/javascript">
     function pa(){
        var fname = document.getElementById('fname').value;
        var lname = document.getElementById('lname').value;
        var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
        if(fname==""||lname==""||email=="")
            alert("Please, Compelete the form...");}
        </script>
    </head> <body>
        <form onsubmit="pa()">
                E-mail Address*<input id="email" value="" name="email" type="text">
                First Name*<input id="fname" value="" name="fname" type="text">
                Last Name*<input id="lname" value="" name="lname" type="text">
                        <input type="submit" value="Register">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hi,above is my code which is causing some problem .i.e,When i press submit button and if the form is incomplete then it has a alert box showing "Please complete the form...".

After i press "ok" the filled data are refreshed.I want to keep the filled data.          I have no idea for this problem.I want my data should remain if the form is incompletely submitted.

pls help me with this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to prevent the submit event to be forwarded. Try with:

```
if (fname==""|| ...) {
   alert('...');
   return false;
}
```

Regards

parascus

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `return false;` to your `onsubmit` function. The problem is that the onsubmit function runs before the page posts the form. This function can return a `true` or `false` boolean indicating whether to repost the page. In your case, you are not returning either, so the page "submits" and reposts and all the user data is gone.

For Example:

```
<form onsubmit="return pa();">
...
</form>
```

And in the pa function:

```
function pa() {
...
    if( some conditional ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `<form onsubmit="pa()">` use   `<form onsubmit=" return pa()">`. in your code return false after u post a alert.this should fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is on approach to helping you out.

1.Connect [jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/) to your page.
2.Place an ID selector on your form element like this...

```
<form id="myform">
```

3.Then add the following script code to your page

```
 $(function() {
 $('#myform').submit(function () {
  pa();
  return false;
  });
 });
```